# htaccess and turning ?page into /(whatthepageis)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, so I am wondering what is the correct way to do .htaccess so that a url like this
http://www.mysite.com/?page=spinme

looks like this

http://www.mysite.com/spinme

It still needs to load index.php

but I am not sure how to do it, I know sounds simple.

Also I need it not to effect images or style sheets that are already

http://www.mysite.com/(what ever the folder link)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Why are you checking for a file or directory? Why are you checking for any string and not just the one asked for?

Comment: That's what the OP asked for: "Also I need it not to effect images or style sheets that are already...". He also said "a url *like*" so I assume he wants to use other URLs with this as well; it's quite a common solution

Comment: *"a url like this"* means one URL. There is no plural given in the question. If you check for a *specific* URL you don't need to stress the file-system for directory *and* file checks. That concrete URL will be checked by the rule not by the file-system. Every other file and directory will just work as it did already, no need to triple the work of the server.

Comment: I would read "*a url like this*" as "*a url **similar to** this*", just vernacular I guess

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f //not to effect images or style sheets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d //not to effect directory's
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why `QSA`? And why to check for a file or directory?

Comment: I always append the query string, this opens the option to grab GET variables that are not passed through the router/front controller, if you dont check that its not a file/folder then a request to a stylesheet or folder will just get passed to the mod rewrite.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for,
Just wondering am I able to add more variables to it like &location= or &search

Comment: @RussellHarrower: That's what `QSA` is for, just type it in: `http://www.mysite.com/spinme?location=paris&search=fromage`

Comment: yeah with `QSA` you can pass parameters like `./spinme?location=bla` or you can use `/spinme/bla` then handle splitting with `/` as the delimiter

Comment: Hi, that works however it seems if the user goes to http://mysite.com/spinme/bla all my design disappears

Answer (score 0):

To make

```
http://www.mysite.com/?page=spinme
```

to look like

```
http://www.mysite.com/spinme
```

You first of all need to make each output of that URI to be

```
http://www.mysite.com/spinme
```

That step is very important (at least for the display, in terms of working, you can skip this step and your site will just work).

If you've managed that, in your `.htaccess` file, just add a single rule:

```
RewriteRule ^spinme$ index.php?page=spinme [L]
```

and you're done.

If you're concerned about Search Engine Optimization (SEO) you should use this URI instead:

```
http://www.mysite.com/?page=spinme
```

It will show the search engine that your site has pages and they have a name. That's additional information searchengines process nowadays, comparable to keywords in earlier days.

Hope this is helpful.